# Lambda function in classes

Tags: python, class, lambda

```
class Test:
   def generate_attachment(self, type, owner_id, media_id):
       return type + str(owner_id) + '_' + str(media_id)
```

How to represent this function like a lambda function?
Do I need mark 'self' in the lambda variables?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can just do this:

```
my_lambda = lambda type, owner_id, media_id: type + str(owner_id) + '_' + str(media_id)
```

Using a parameter called `type` is a bad idea though since a function by that name already exists in Python and you overwrite it.

Comment: You won't be able to call it like a method, though. Or rather, the `type` parameter will be the instance the "method" was called on. So you'd call it like `t = Test(); t.my_lambda(owner_id, media_id)`, and `type` would be the `t` object. Probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: As provided, the function doesn't use `self`.

Comment: `self` (the object of a method call) is always passed to a method as the first parameter.